# Windows Vista partition will not resize using normal tools. Any advice?

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning

I have a 120GB hard drive split into two partitions (C and D). Windows Vista is installed on the C partition with most of my files on D.

As I am starting to run out of space within the C drive of my laptop I want to take 20GB of space from the D partition and add it to C, but after trying out the Disk Management application that comes with Vista I have been able to take space from D but not extend it to C. I've also tried using the command line but received an error once again.

I don't really want to have to reinstall everything again, and I've heard that many of the typical programs out there tend not to work so well with Vista. Is there any way to extend the space on C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

[Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) allows you to rearrange, shrink, grow and do many "funky" things with hard drives.

It may not work if you have a special setup or use Bitlocker/Full Drive encryption.

Comment: In the end, after a bit of tweaking, I managed to get it working with Gparted. The laptop's running perfectly now and to my knowledge there are no problems and the speed has definitely increased. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/

Courtesy of the how-to-geek:

> Resize a Partition for Free in Windows
>   7 or Vista
>
> Windows 7 and Vista include a built-in
>   functionality in Disk Management to
>   shrink and expand partitions. No more
>   3rd party utilities needed!
>
> To get to this utility, open up
>   Control Panel, and type in partition
>   into the search box.. you’ll
>   immediately see the link show up:
>
> Shrink a Partition
>
> In the Disk Management screen, just
>   right-click on the partition that you
>   want to shrink, and select “Shrink
>   Volume” from the menu.
>
> In the Shrink dialog, you will want to
>   enter the amount you want to shrink
>   by, not the new size. For example, if
>   you want to shrink your 50gb partition
>   by roughly 10gb so that it will now be
>   roughly 40gb, enter 10000 into the
>   box:
>
> Extend a Partition
>
> In the Disk Management screen, just
>   right-click on the partition that you
>   want to shrink, and select “Extend
>   Volume” from the menu.
>
> On this screen, you can specify the
>   amount that you want to increase the
>   partition by. In this case, I’m going
>   to extend it back to the roughly 50GB
>   size that it was before.
>
> Note that the extend partition feature
>   only works with contiguous space.

Does that help?

Comment: I've already used this tool and it managed to shrink the D drive, but not extend the C drive.

Comment: probably not, the 'contigeous space' bit is a downer for this scenario. which is getting us to the next problem: if you get it done with gparted would be that the C drive in the end  will not be contigeous and that can cause performance issues. i'd backup the files on D:, ghost the C: drive to image, then repartition the drive to my likings (e.g. with Vista setup), deploy the C drive image and then restore the backed up files to D: and everything is hunky dory. painless and secure. ghost ain't free but Clonezilla should do the trick since the new C: drive will be larger than the old partition.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista has the ability to shrink and expand partition in disk management, but there must be unallocated space clinging to the partition which you want to expand. If there is no unallocated space clinging to the partition which you want to expand, how to expand this partition with this unallocated space? A thirty party tool is a best choice, easeus partition master is free for windows home users, the detailed method, please visit: http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/partition-magic-vista.htm

Answer (score 0):

Another Free Windows partitioning software

http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

.

"How to" section at the bottom of this page

http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/