# How to create partition in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning, windows-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Vista partition will not resize using normal tools. Any advice?](https://superuser.com/questions/87157/windows-vista-partition-will-not-resize-using-normal-tools-any-advice)

How to create a partition while Windows Vista already on single hard drive?

Please provide tools and steps.

Comment: Use Partition Magic Tool for partitioning. This is the best tool I have ever used for partitioning. Here is the link [Partition Magic](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/Partition-Magic.shtml)

Comment: PM 8 will not work well on Vista, causes more problems, use a modern partitioning software.

Answer (score 0):

Open your start menu, right click on computer, then go to manage, go to storage, and then partitioning... This is the same for all windows versions

Answer (score 0):

Use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)  you can boot it from CD or a USB key, instructions [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).

Make sure you backup important stuff before you mess with partitions